# Strange errors using NEOS server

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi, neos-server

Im trying to use NEOS server and I get the following error:

[image]

Im getting this using both MINTO solver and Gurobi solver. I dont get this error when I conduct optimization at my work, but I do using my home computer. Does anyone have any idea how to get the usual way of receiving errors back?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I've forgotten about this question, but since I recently got an upvote for it I'm thinking I can post how I've solved it.

Basically in my comments I had a strange character, a "[]" but with black inside. Simply removing this solved this error. I'm guessing it was a character not supported. I think the character originally was an "å" (a common letter in Swedish). Hopefully this helps someone